# Finding VSTO Log

Tags: c#, logging, vsto, word-2007, word-2010

I'm trying to run a Word 2007 in a Word 2010. But an error occurs on COM initialization and I can't find any log of this error.

I'm using `VSTO_LOGALERTS=1` and  `VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS=0` but no log is showed on `Word 2010`, only in `Word 2007`.

There is any special configuration to make it works?

Comment: Did you try to switch on this option: Word Options > Advanced > General > "Show add-in user interface errors"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you use ClickOne to deploy it?
Try to do next:
Copy all addIn files to some folder, e.g. C:\Test

Create reg file and run it to add to registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins\YourAddin]
"Description"="YourAddin"
"FriendlyName"="YourAddin"
"LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
"Manifest"="file:///C:/Test/YourAddin.vsto|vstolocal"
```

"|vstolocal" means do not copy addIn to assembly cash.
After an error occurs in C:\Test folder should appears log file named "YourAddin.vsto.log"